# Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get this bootstrap dropdown code to "dropdown".

I am running this in a MEAN (angular js) environment.

The html works perfectly, but there is no "dropdown" element to it.
[image]

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Change Customer<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#!">Customer</a></li>
<li><a href="#!">Customer</a></li>
<li><a href="#!">Customer</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>
```

Why does the dropdown functionality not appear?

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap javascript? I'm not 100% sure but think it's needed for this

Comment: Do you use original Bootstrap JS code (which uses jQuery), or **UI Bootstrap**, which is rewritten JS code to Angular directives?

Comment: While I was working with Bootstrap I wrote this small gist as a guide check it out [gist](https://gist.github.com/KhaledMohamedP/fe09a24b582e5679d802). In general you missed to include bootstrap `.js` file, you also need jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you did not included Bootstrap javascript

add this at the end of your body section

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check there's everything you need in your file.

Somewhere in your html there should be this (if you're using CDN):

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Source for code is obviously [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

The best practice is to put it at the end of the html file for reducing loading time.